# Read part of a single line in python

Tags: python, file

I have a list of proxy's that i want to check if they are active before printing them:

```
line = random.choice(open('proxys.txt').readlines())
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + line)
if response == 0:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("proxy is alive")

else:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Proxy is dead")
```

but it cant ping the proxy as it has :port at the end. is there any way to fix this?

Comment: just take whatever is left of the `:` by adding following line as second line: `line = line.split(":")[0]`

Answer (score 0):

If you have lines like `host:port`, you can just split the info by `:` and get the first value like this: `line.split(':')[0]`